# tsql to know when dbcc checkdb was run on a database last time

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

Using Tsql, how can i know when DBCC checkdb was last run on SQL server (2000, 2005 or 2008)?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on 2005 and up you can run

```
DBCC DBINFO ('YourDatabaseName') WITH TABLERESULTS
```

look for dbi_dbccLastKnownGood

Answer (score 5):

Try this to check all DB's on SQL 2005 onwards

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DBCC TRACEON (3604);

CREATE TABLE #temp (
        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
        ParentObject VARCHAR(255),
        [Object] VARCHAR(255),
        Field VARCHAR(255),
        [Value] VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE #Results (
        DBName VARCHAR(255),
        LastGoodDBCC VARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE looping_cursor CURSOR
FOR

SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(500),databasepropertyex(name, 'Status'),0) = 'ONLINE'

OPEN looping_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM looping_cursor INTO @Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #temp
        EXECUTE('DBCC PAGE (['+@Name+'], 1, 9, 3)WITH TABLERESULTS');

        INSERT INTO #Results
        SELECT @Name,MAX(VALUE) FROM #temp
        WHERE Field = 'dbi_dbccLastKnownGood';

    FETCH NEXT FROM looping_cursor INTO @Name
    END
CLOSE looping_cursor;
DEALLOCATE looping_cursor;

SELECT DBName
    ,ISNULL(LastGoodDBCC,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') AS 'LastGoodDBCC'
FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #temp
DROP TABLE #Results
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting with SQL Server 2016 SP2 you could use:

```
SELECT  DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'LastGoodCheckDbTime')
```

[DATABASEPROPERTYEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> LastGoodCheckDbTime
>
> **The date and time of the last successful DBCC CHECKDB to run on the specified database.**
>
> NULL = Input not valid  Base data type: datetime

Comment: @user2608613 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd45068f959d7ab5051e5c3237dc0d96 Please define  not working: incorrect result/NULL/no result at all

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/CHECKDB-From-Every-Angle-When-did-DBCC-CHECKDB-last-run-successfully.aspx:

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604); 
GO

-- page 9 is the boot page
DBCC PAGE (dbname, 1, 9, 3);
GO
```

> You need to look for the
>   dbi_dbccLastKnownGood field. That was
>   the last time that DBCC CHECKDB ran
>   without finding any corruptions.

Answer (score 3):

The query above produces incorrect results because the #temp table is not truncated within the cursor

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DBCC TRACEON (3604);

CREATE TABLE #temp (
        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
        ParentObject VARCHAR(255),
        [Object] VARCHAR(255),
        Field VARCHAR(255),
        [Value] VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE #Results (
        DBName VARCHAR(255),
        LastGoodDBCC VARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE looping_cursor CURSOR
FOR

SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(500),databasepropertyex(name, 'Status'),0) = 'ONLINE'

OPEN looping_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM looping_cursor INTO @Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #temp
        EXECUTE('DBCC PAGE (['+@Name+'], 1, 9, 3)WITH TABLERESULTS');

        INSERT INTO #Results
        SELECT @Name,MAX(VALUE) FROM #temp
        WHERE Field = 'dbi_dbccLastKnownGood';

        truncate table #temp

    FETCH NEXT FROM looping_cursor INTO @Name
    END
CLOSE looping_cursor;
DEALLOCATE looping_cursor;

SELECT DBName
    ,ISNULL(LastGoodDBCC,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') AS 'LastGoodDBCC'
FROM #Results
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ola Hallengren’s maintenance scripts then this information would be saved in the `CommandLog` table. The below is how to get all DBCC_CHECKDB executions from the last week:

```
USE [master]
GO

SELECT *
FROM [CommandLog]
WHERE [CommandType] ='DBCC_CHECKDB'
AND (CONVERT([datetime], [StartTime], 102) >= GETDATE() - 7) 
ORDER BY [StartTime], [EndTime]
```